# Cast operation precedence in C#

Tags: c#, casting, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

Will the differences below matter significantly in C#?

```
int a, b;
double result;
result = (double)a / b;
result = a / (double)b;
result = (double)a / (double)b;
```

Which one do you use?

Comment: Just make sure you do NOT use `result = (double)(a/b);`

Comment: None of these are even required. `a` and `b` are already doubles. the result variable is a double. The only thing that won't be a double is the division result of two doubles. If I am not mistaken there is natural casting from an integer to doule in a case like this.

Comment: @Ramhound `a` and `b` are integers, not doubles. Doing `result = a / b` will result in an integer division, then a cast into double.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cast will occur before the division.

In your examples, it doesn't matter which one you do as if one operand is a double, the runtime will cast/convert the other to a double as well.

This looks like a micro-optimization - not something worth worrying about or dealing with unless measurements show it is indeed a bottleneck.

Comment: My main concern is precision at the end of the calculation. I was afraid that whichever one I choose to cast (first, explicitly) makes a difference. But since you say the internals will cast everyone of them, I'll trust you.

Comment: @Jake - trust, but verify... This is something you can _easily_ test on your own (just write a small application that does the different types of calculations).

Comment: Actually, the small application will not prove anything. A small subset of test operands cannot represent the outcome for all possible operands, unless it is first determined that it is implemented as such. Hence I had to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

I do this:

```
result = (double)a / (double)b;
```

It may be strictly unnecessary, but generally I want to make *sure* that it will not do integer division, and I don't really care to remember the specific rules for this scenario, so  it's easier (if a few more keystrokes) to be explicit.

Comment: Actually I am doing this *because* I don't bother to remember the specifics. But I decide to change my lazy habits, hence I asked this question. (btw, I didn't give you the -1)

Answer (score 2):

I do `(double)a / b` because I imagine an int to be something indivisible like a rock or something. When cast to a double it becomes divisible, like a cake. You can divide 3.0 cakes in four parts, but you can't divide three rocks in 4.0 parts. Or something. Do make any sense?